# process xml datatype with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery Get request to retrieve data from a web service. The web service sends me back xml data such as `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">false</boolean>`
How can I take this data and parse through it, also what if there are multiple nodes? can i convert this to json or something more readable and easy to parse? Thanks for any help

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "https://domain/MainService.asmx/LoginMobile",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: parameter,
                    dataType: "jsonp"
```

EDIT: Here is my call. I would like to receive json data but this is coming back as xml.

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public bool LoginMobile(string userName, string password)
    {
        return Users.GetLoginInfo(userName, password);
    }
```

EDIT:Webservice Method

Comment: can you post the web service code, it seems that the server is returning the xml, also i dont think there is a property of ajax as method, type is set to `GET`

Comment: @user516883 Check my edit, your ajax call is incorrect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want json then the best way would be to configure the server to send `json`

you can use [`.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
$.get("/path.php",function(data){
 var $xml = $(data).parseXML();
});
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my edit. I would like to recieve json data back but i get back xml

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`parseXml`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) in jQuery, then you can use selectors and functions as if it was HTML.

**EDIT:** Based on your update, it seems your ajax call isn't set up to receive XML, it's set up to receive JSON. Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    datatype: "xml",
    url: "https://domain/MainService.asmx/LoginMobile",
    data: parameter,
    success: function (result) {
        var xml = $.parseXML(result);
        //now do whatever with your XML
    }
});
```

Comment: Now it does not even work at all I get thisRequest Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:origin, content-type, accept
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive

Comment: Look at the request method it says options

Comment: @user516883 take out `method: Get` also, that's not needed.

Comment: @user516883 I've rewritten your AJAX call to retrieve XML, try my new edit :)

Comment: Now it doesnt even make the call. I am getting an Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin